# How to use find with already written script?

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos, find

I know how to find last modified files, but how do I use it with my already written script. In folder I have hundreds of files `xyz_<yyyymm>`, now I use `$ find /home/directory/TEST/ -type f -mmin -60`, but it crashes halfway.

Comment: What are you trying to do with your "already written script" and `find`?  I don't see any reference to a script in your `find` command

Comment: my script is just some sed and mv lines, i put $ find on top of it, how to make connection with "already written script" :D thx for answer

Comment: you want to do something with each file? `find ... | xargs script`

Comment: Does your script expect to operate on a file, and you want `find` to invoke your script for each appropriate file?

Comment: I have 10 files `xyz1` modified today and 20 `xyz2` modified 2 days ago. I've already written some lines that take `xyz*` file rename it and then `.zip.` it. All I need now is to take last modified files (10files from today) and execute my "already written script"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute a script for each result of a find command, you could use `xargs`, but often I prefer to use `-exec` with find.  So you could do it like:

```
find /home/directory/TEST/ -type f -mmin -60 -exec /path/to/your/script {} \;
```

and the name of the file that `find` matches will be put in the `{}` spot for each match

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is use `find` to iterate over numerous files and then pass each file name to a script, you can use `xargs`, especially if the file list is very large and you find things crashing part way through.

Here, I iterate over the current working directory looking for all files, then pass each file name to a perl script which simply prints out the name:

```
find . -type f | xargs -0 ./script.pl
```

You can adjust your `find` command string to suit your needs.

Comment: I got this:`sed -e 's/TIMESTAMP*\([0-9]*\)/\1/g' TIMESTAMP_old_*.csv> new.txt
sed -i -e 1d new.txt
find /home/TEST/ -type f -name "CERTIFICATE_*.csv" -exec mv {} CERTIFICATE_"$(cat new.txt)".csv \;` how to make it work on last modified files, files called CERTIFICATE are hundreds, how to take the newer one. i got trouble with understanding xargs